# What is the best practice to show errors when parsing a large csv file?

Tags: usability, errors

I am designing the experience for uploading and validating a large CSV file, which can possibly have as many as 20,000 rows.

It will really help if there was some way to show the user all the row numbers which have errors, as well as that the error is.
It's OK if there are 10-15 errors, but what if there are 1000+ rows that have errors?

Currently, I am planning to solve this problem by not mentioning faulty row numbers at all but just showing all the possible types of errors that may be in the file. See below -

[image]

What is the best way to show errors for large files and when there can be thousands of errors, and to make the errors as helpful and descriptive to the users as possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd give back a CSV file with the result of the error (and the success). On the website just tell the error numbers and types.